# How do you get an image stored in a SQL Database and display it in a carosel? (Ruby on rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Ive been trying to wrap my head around this and find a solution but I feel like Ive hit a stump. Im trying to grab the first, second, or third photo from my SQL database and feed it into my bootstrap carousel on my homepage.  This is my code for my photos controller:

```
  class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  # GET /photos.json
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  # GET /photos/1.json
  def show
  end
  def show_first
    @photos = Photo.find(1)
    send_data @photos.image, :type => 'image/*',:disposition => 'inline'
  end
  def show_second
    @photos = Photo.find(2)
    send_data @photos.image, :type => 'image/*',:disposition => 'inline'
  end
  def show_third
    @photos = Photo.find(3)
    send_data @photos.image, :type => 'image/*',:disposition => 'inline'
  end

  def show_image
    @photos = Photo.find(params[:id])
    send_data @photos.image, :type => 'image/*',:disposition => 'inline'
  end
  # GET /photos/new
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  # GET /photos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  # DELETE /photos/1.json
  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :medium, :description, :file)
    end
end
```

Ive been looking up and trying to find a good and simple way to accomplish this. And have tried to use the methods like show_first, second, etc. But Im not sure if I am even implementing it right. Would any be able to shed some light on this or at least point me in the right direction? Is the image/* right? Im basically doing my learning on my own and any help and thorough explanation would be awesome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it in the `show` action?

```
# GET photos/:id
# GET photos/:id.jpg
def show
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.jpg do
      send_data @photos.image, type: 'image/jpeg', disposition: 'inline'
    end
  end
end
```

You can then display the photos by:

```
<% Photo.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10).each do |photo| %>
  <%= tag :img, src: path_for(photo, format: :jpg) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would consider using ActiveStorage and storing the photos on a CDN as it will be much faster than your rails server serving files.

Comment: Ill give this a shot, its saying that there is an exception with the path_for.

Comment: its composed of a id, name, medium, description, and file.